# DataGridView slow to refresh on screen

Tags: vb.net, performance, datagridview, datatable, refresh

I have a program that regularly updates a few datagridviews with new data that is received via TCP. The problem I am having is that the screen refresh is quite slow. Bellow is a stripped back version of my code. This example takes 1.1s to update the screen each time the loop in StartButton_Click is iterated. How can I make this faster without reducing the amount of data that is shown?

I added a stopwatch to try and work out what lines of code were causing the biggest issue. From the tests, it seemed that the main issue was updating the datagridview cells with a new number.

I'm not sure how to make this faster as my program relies on the values being updated regularly. Is a datagridview not the right object for this application? Should i be using something else? Is there a way to get a datagridview to update faster?

Public Class Form1

```
Public DataTable1 As New DataTable

Private Sub Load_From(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable1

    Me.Height = 700
    Me.Width = 1000
    DataGridView1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    DataGridView1.Width = Me.Width - 10
    DataGridView1.Height = Me.Height - 10

    For c As Integer = 0 To 20
        DataTable1.Columns.Add("col" & c)
        If DataTable1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            DataTable1.Rows.Add()
        End If
        DataGridView1.Columns(c).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None '0%

        DataTable1.Rows(0).Item(c) = "col" & c
        DataGridView1.Columns(c).Width = 40
        'Header
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(c).Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(c).Style.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(c).Style.Font = New Font("Verdana", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
        'Data
        DataGridView1.Columns(c).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        DataGridView1.Columns(c).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False
        DataGridView1.Columns(c).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
    Next

    For r As Integer = 1 To 25
        DataTable1.Rows.Add()
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click

    Dim stpw As New Stopwatch
    stpw.Reset()
    stpw.Start()

    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Dim rand As New Random
        Dim randnumber As Double = rand.Next(5, 15) / 10

        UpdateDataTable(randnumber)
        DataGridView1.Update()
        Me.Text = i & "/100"
    Next

    stpw.Stop()
    MsgBox(stpw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDataTable(ByVal offset As Double)

    For r As Integer = 1 To DataTable1.Rows.Count - 1 'loop through rows

        For c As Integer = 0 To DataTable1.Columns.Count - 1 '89%

            DataTable1.Rows(r).Item(c) = (r / c) * offset
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Removing the `DataGridView1.Update()` and `Me.Text = i & "/100"` calls from the loop is a good start. There's no reason to force the DGV to manually redraw (update) itself, especially not on every iteration. And setting the text of the form just requires even more unnecessary updating.

Comment: `my program relies on the values being updated regularly`  You should have posted something which shows the real app rather than an artificial test.

Comment: Thaks Visual Vincent and Plutonix I was trying to simplify it by just showing the code that was causing the problem. The full app is about 100,000 lines of code. I replaced how the values are generated with a random number generator. Using stopwatches i have discovered that it is the updaing of the values in the datagrid that is costing the time. The determination of the values is less than 1%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I have to admit that I totally botched my original answer by erroneously believing that the call to `DataGridView.Update` was not needed to emulate the OP conditions.  I am leaving my original text as it may be of use for someone in another situation.

A potential solution is to use a DoubleBuffered `DataGridView`.  This can be accomplished by creating a class that inherits from `DataGridView` and enables DoubleBuffering.

```
Public Class BufferedDataGridView : Inherits DataGridView
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackgroundColor)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Doing this yields a change in appearance in that the client area is black until something is drawn on it.  To alleviate this, the class overrides the OnPaint method to draw a background.

In my testing this reduced the bench-march time from approximately 2600 ms to approximately 600 ms.

**End Edit**

---

In addition to the highly pertinent suggestions of @Visual Vincent in the comments regarding eliminating unnecessary updating, I would recommend that you use a [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to encapsulate the `DataTable` and use that as the `DataGridview.DataSource`.

```
Private bs As New BindingSource

Private Sub Load_From(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bs.DataSource = DataTable1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```

This will allow you to temporary suspend change events raised through the `DataTable` that cause the `DataGridView` to repaint cells.

```
Private Sub UpdateDataTable(ByVal offset As Double)
    ' prevent each item change from raising an event that causes a redraw
    bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = False

    For r As Integer = 1 To DataTable1.Rows.Count - 1 'loop through rows
        For c As Integer = 0 To DataTable1.Columns.Count - 1 '89%
            DataTable1.Rows(r).Item(c) = (r / c) * offset
        Next
    Next

    bs.RaiseListChangedEvents = True ' re-enable change events
    bs.ResetBindings(False) ' Force bound controls to re-read list
End Sub
```

This way the will only repaint once to reflect all the changes to the underlying `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion TnTinMn I have just tested it and unfortunatly it did not update any faster (actually 5% slower). The data comes in via TCP and is then shuffled and organised and displayed in a datagrid. The data is constantly being transmitted and my application requires it to be constantly updated with the latest data. So i need the update to be as fast as possible to avoid any lag. I'm starting to think that this is the limit of a datagridview of this size. Perhaps I need to use an array of labels instead.

Comment: @jasonwcgray, I badly botched my original answer and have posted an alternative that should help your situation.

Comment: Hi TnTinMn I finally got a chance to try your revised double buffered suggestion. However, I think I am missing something. Do I need to add anything to the Form1 class? i just copied your code bellow the Form1 class but it still takes the same time and doens't seem to run through the BufferedDataGridView class code when I add a breakpoint.

Comment: @jasonwcgray, Just adding the code to your project will do no good.  You need to use it. After building the project you should see a new control in the Toolbox. It will be at listed at the top of the toolbox under _Project Name_ Components.  Use it as a replacement for the standard DataGridView control.  Alternatively, you could edit the Form.designer.vb file and change the type definition of DataGridView1 from System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView to BufferedDataGridView .  There will be to locations to make the change. The 1st is where it is instantiated and the 2nd is the field definition.

Comment: I just gave it a test. That works great. Thanks for your help TnTinMn